# moment.js issue on firefox

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer, firefox, momentjs

This code works fine on chrome but does not work on firefox or IE.
Note that it works fine when I remove the "+00:00"

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var now = moment("Sun Jun 01 2016 05:00:00+00:00").format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ssZ');
 alert(now);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't pass the format of the string to parse, you're relying on *moment.js* guessing the format and if it can't get something that looks like a valid date (it may still be incorrect), it will fall back to parsing by the built–in Date constructor, which is strongly recommended against. The *format* method is for the output format, not the parse format.

To pass the format of the string to the moment.js parser, include it as the second argument:

```
moment("Sun Jun 01 2016 05:00:00+00:00",'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ssZ').format(/*output format*/)
```

Note also that where it falls back to built–in parsing, the following warning is displayed in the console:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

Comment: Thanks - that works. I assumed that the format is for the input and not output

Comment: I guess it's one of those API decisions: should there be *parse* and *format* methods, or assume one and only have a method for the other?